# Punctuation! Semi-colon use in a list?

Tags: semicolons

Can anyone help with this sentence? Is my punctuation here correct?

If you sell bicycles, sell as many accessories as you can; water bottles; pumps; and biking gear, such as shoes, gloves, caps and more.

Answer (score 1):

> If you sell bicycles, sell as many accessories as you can: water
>   bottles, pumps, and biking gear such as shoes, gloves, caps, and more.

A colon before the list of accessories you can sell, and commas instead of semi-colons because you're separating the list items. You don't need a colon for "such as" even though it's a list, because saying "such as" implies a list is to follow. Also, I enjoy a good Oxford comma, so in it went.